# Adding doc value in mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I'm trying to find the average of values in an object. The values are save in mongodb but as strings. I want to find the average and return on a table.

docs:

```
{
{
  "_id": "someId",
  "english": "78",
  "literature": "78",
  "period": "1st Period"
}{
  "_id": "someId",
  "english": "90",
  "literature": "90",
  "period": "2nd Period"
}{
  "_id": "someId",
  "english": "70",
  "literature": "99",
  "period": "3rd Period"
}{
  "_id": "someId",
  "english": "50",
  "literature": "60",
  "period": "First Sem. Exam"
}{
  "_id": "someId",
  "english": "68",
  "literature": "88",
  "period": "4th Period"
}{
  "_id": "someId",
  "Average": "",
  "period": "First Sem. Average"
}{
  "_id": "someId",
  "english": "40",
  "literature": "77",
  "period": "5th Period"
}{
  "_id": "someId",
  "english": "70",
  "literature": "66",
  "period": "6th Period"
}{
  "_id": "someId",
  "english": "55",
  "literature": "79",
  "period": "Second Sem. Exam"
}{
  "_id": "someId",
  "Average": "",
  "period": "Second Sem. Average"
}
}
```

As mentioned in the doc, I want to get the average of `1st Period, 2nd Period, 3rd Period` and `First Sem. Exam` and return it in a table

[image: Currently returning the values on a table but want to add the averages for each subject]

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having in mind that `docs` is an array, this should give you a pretty good idea how to get the english average. You first extract the four period you want from the array. Then you extract the result you want. Finally, you simply do the average.

```
const filteredDocs = docs.filter(element => {
    return (
        element.period === "1st Period" ||
        element.period === "2nd Period" ||
        element.period === "3rd Period" ||
        element.period === "First Sem. Exam"
    );
});

const englishResults = filteredDocs.map(element => {
    return parseInt(element.english);
});

const englishAverage =
    englishResults.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / englishResults.length;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.